# How do I stop a trigger in an infinite loop?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, database-trigger

Let's say I did something really stupid by creating a trigger that has an infinite loop in it. It's not nesting, or recursive; I just have a `WHILE` loop in it that apparently isn't exiting.

Now I can't access the trigger at all... I can't update it, can't drop it, can't disable it. And none of my programs that use the table it's attached to can do anything with the table because of it. I've exited all the way out of SQL Server, but when I get back in, I have the same issue.

Any way to kill that trigger?

Comment: Is this in production? Any chance of rebooting the server?

Comment: Luckily for me, I'm still in a development environment. I don't have permission to reboot the server, but I can ask those who do.

Comment: either that, or if you EXEC sp_who2 it should tell you all active connections, you could see if it's one of these and then kill it (hint: use DBCC INPUTBUFFER(spid) to see what commands are being run)

Comment: Rebooting the server did it. I guess I'm a little surprised they didn't create an easier way out of something like that.

Comment: if it's running under the same spid then it might show in sp_who2 if you can catch it. then a simple kill (SPID) will get rid of it. That's pretty extreme though

Comment: Hey, that's cool. I used your DBCC thing and found it right away and killed it. I'm not sure why it was still around after rebooting the server; maybe it was a subsequent one I found, who knows. In any case, much thanks for the advice. Always learning on this stuff.

Comment: Aren't we all :) As the answer posted also resolves the issue it may be wise to mark it as the accepted answer so the question in closed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provided that you have the requisite permissions here is what you can do:

Open / Run SSMS and connect to the server in question.
Change to use the correct database

in SSMS, run `SP_Who2`

This gives you a list of all connections, and their state.

Take any one connection `SPID#` and run `DBCC INPUTBUFFER (SPID#)`

If that connection is running your trigger, you can kill the connection by issuing `KILL SPID#`

Then read up on why to avoid triggers.